# Securing specific Document fields in Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a simple system that allows users to create an account with info that they provided. Right now, I store all the data in a Collection `users` which has some Documents that represents users.
I'd like to keep some sensitive data of the user, such as the email address and phone number, private. In Firebase Database I would've created something like this:

```
  users: {
    uid: {
      public_info:...
      private_info:...
    }
  }
```

Protecting the data in here is pretty straight forward. I would simply write different rule sets for the `private_info` and `public_info`.
How would something like this be achieved in Firestore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use different top-level collections for user public and private data, and set their rules appropriately.

Comment: Is this really the only way? I thought Firestore would make it easier to nest data.

Comment: Alternatively you could have a subcollection for each user that contains their private data. You grant public access to the top-level collection, and private access to the subcollections. But it seems a bit overboard to use a sub-collection on each user for that, and it's not possible to protect a subset of a document.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case you have two reasonably useful options:

Have a top level collection (public) with a sub collection called something like "private_data" (private) and grant access accordingly.

--OR--

Have a top level collection (private) with a sub collection called something like "public_data" (public) and grand access accordingly.